# Does the Update Manager in Linux distributions update packages installed via the terminal?

Tags: linux

If I have installed packages via the terminal e.g. apt-get install flashplugin-installer, are updates available via the Update Manager?

Comment: If you are talking about Debian system like in your example, yes, but don't try to e.g. mix rpm and yum in weird ways.

Comment: @honk - Please see my comment below to akira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. coz the "Update Manager" is just a shiny shell around the command-line technology.

Comment: Why is that I have an older version of Flash installed and Update Manager has not eluded to me to update it?

Comment: specify "older". specify "older than what". aside from that: if it is not showing up in the repositories (which are the backend of the update-manager-stuff) then it won't show you that there is something "new" .. coz it bases it's decision upon those repositories.

Comment: When I say older, I mean an older version. For example I have .62 installed however I am aware that .63 is available. So if a patch is critical as is in the case of Adobe Flash, why would a repository not be updated? How long does it take a repository to announce updates?

Comment: it takes as long as the folks who maintain the repositories need to integrate it.

Comment: How do you keep on top of critical patches then?

Comment: 2 options: you wait for the stuff pop up in the repositories OR you are applying the patches yourself. aside all of that: your question is answered.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2723/discussion-between-akira-and-peanutsmonkey)